# Why Flutter build apk generating unusual type of apk file?

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

`flutter build apk` command creating unusual type of apk which can not be installed in android. here is the image of built apk which is not opening anymore.

[image]

And below is the another apk image which was working fine previously
[image]

The working apk showing APK after file size whereas another apk showing Binary.

Answer (score 0):

finally i solved this issue by adding `shrinkResources false` in `android>app>build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           shrinkResources false
        }
    }
```